# Unable to install pwn package for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-packaging

While trying to install pwn package for Python 2.7, I encountered an error about `capstone.dll`. I tried to install using the command line and using PyCharm, but it shows the same error.

Here's the installation's log:

```
Collecting pwn
  Using cached pwn-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting pwntools (from pwn)
  Using cached pwntools-3.1.1.tar.gz
Collecting paramiko>=1.15.2 (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached paramiko-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mako>=1.0.0 (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached Mako-1.0.6.tar.gz
Collecting pyelftools>=0.2.4 (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached pyelftools-0.24.tar.gz
Collecting capstone (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached capstone-3.0.4.tar.gz
Collecting ropgadget>=5.3 (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached ROPGadget-5.4.tar.gz
Collecting pyserial>=2.7 (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached pyserial-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=2.0 in c:\python27x64\lib\site-packages (from pwntools->pwn)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pip>=6.0.8 in c:\python27x64\lib\site-packages (from pwntools->pwn)
Collecting tox>=1.8.1 (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached tox-2.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pygments>=2.0 in c:\python27x64\lib\site-packages (from pwntools->pwn)
Collecting pysocks (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached PySocks-1.5.7.tar.gz
Collecting python-dateutil (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pypandoc (from pwntools->pwn)
  Downloading pypandoc-1.3.3-py2-none-win_amd64.whl (21.5MB)
Collecting packaging (from pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached packaging-16.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psutil>=2.1.3 (from pwntools->pwn)
  Downloading psutil-5.0.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (177kB)
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7 (from paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.1.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=1.1 (from paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools->pwn)
  Downloading cryptography-1.5.3-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl (1.3MB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.9.2 (from mako>=1.0.0->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-0.23.tar.gz
Collecting pluggy<0.5.0,>=0.3.0 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached pluggy-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting py>=1.4.17 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached py-1.4.31-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting virtualenv>=1.11.2 (from tox>=1.8.1->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached virtualenv-15.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in c:\python27x64\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil->pwntools->pwn)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\python27x64\lib\site-packages (from pypandoc->pwntools->pwn)
Collecting wheel>=0.25.0 (from pypandoc->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cffi>=1.4.1 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools->pwn)
  Downloading cffi-1.9.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl (154kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached idna-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipaddress (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached ipaddress-1.0.17-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): enum34 in c:\python27x64\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools->pwn)
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.4.1->cryptography>=1.1->paramiko>=1.15.2->pwntools->pwn)
  Using cached pycparser-2.17.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyasn1, pycparser, cffi, idna, ipaddress, cryptography, paramiko, MarkupSafe, mako, pyelftools, capstone, ropgadget, pyserial, pluggy, py, virtualenv, tox, pysocks, python-dateutil, wheel, pypandoc, pyparsing, packaging, psutil, pwntools, pwn
  Running setup.py install for pycparser: started
    Running setup.py install for pycparser: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: started
    Running setup.py install for MarkupSafe: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for mako: started
    Running setup.py install for mako: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for pyelftools: started
    Running setup.py install for pyelftools: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for capstone: started
    Running setup.py install for capstone: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Python27x64\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Amit\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\capstone\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\amit\appdata\local\temp\pip-ok0oub-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib
    creating build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\arm.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\arm64.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\arm64_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\arm_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\hexagon.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\hexagon_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\mips.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\mips_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\ppc.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\ppc_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\sparc.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\sparc_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\systemz.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\sysz_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\x86.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\x86_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\xcore.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\xcore_const.py -> build\lib\capstone
    copying capstone\__init__.py -> build\lib\capstone
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running build_clib
    running custom_build_clib
    building 'capstone' library
    'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    running install_lib
    creating C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\arm.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\arm64.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\arm64_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\arm_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\hexagon.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\hexagon_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\mips.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\mips_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\ppc.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\ppc_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\sparc.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\sparc_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\systemz.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\sysz_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\x86.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\x86_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\xcore.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\xcore_const.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    copying build\lib\capstone\__init__.py -> C:\Python27x64\Lib\site-packages\capstone
    warning: install_lib: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    running install_data
    error: can't copy 'src\build\capstone.dll': doesn't exist or not a regular file
```

I searched on the internet for solution with no success.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve this? i am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the system is missing (or can't find) the `cmake` program. Try installing `cmake` on your machine (I'm assuming windows?) and make sure its in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `Capstone` for Python solved the issue:
http://www.capstone-engine.org/download.html